# Inject in Dagger an object with needs activity to be created

Tags: android-activity, dagger-2, inject

Greeting all!

Please help me to figure out if the scenario, I need to cope with, which meets the Dagger concepts.

I have to inject a class into my Activity which needs this activity to be created. The only way comes to my mind is to add the activity to the Model and use it in the object Provides method. does it sound like a normal usage scenario.

```
@Module
public class SampleDiModule {
  private Activity activity;

  public SampleDiModule(Activity activity){
     this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Provides
  @ModuleScope
  public InjectedObject provideInjectedObject(){
     return new InjectedObject.createForAcivity(activity)
  }
}
```

My intention to inject an activity presenter, the presenter depends on a object which could be created only by the object factory in the following way

```
public MyPresentor(InjectedObject object){
}


InjectedObject object = InjectedObjectFactory.forActivity(this)
```

Thanks

Comment: If that is what you need, you are most probably doing something wrong. Generally, with dependency injection you are generating dependency _tree_. If you have two classes referencing each other, you are making a cycle, which is not a tree. If you could elaborate why do you need an actitivity reference inside the class, I'd be happy to elaborate what are you doing wrong and explain it how to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for quick response, I updated the ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are multiple ways to achieve this.

Two of them are on top of my mind.

First, using Dagger scopes. You can create @Activity scope which will manage objects that have life bound to life of particular activities. When creating dagger module that is scoped to Activity, you can pass an activity reference as constructor parameter, and then use it. Something like this (in pseudocode):

```
class ActivityScopedModule {

   ActivityScopedModule(Activity: activity) {
       this.activity = activity;
   }

   CustomObject provideCustomObject() {
       return new CustomObject(this.activity);
   }
```

}

Important thing is that modules that are scoped to activity must be instantiated from `Activity.onCreate()` Here you can find more about creating dagger scopes: http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/ Or in this three-part series: https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-part-i-basic-principles-graph-dependencies-scopes-3dfd032ccd82

Another approach, the easier one, would be to, instead of using static `InjectedObjectFactory.forActivity(this)`, to make it as non-static class `InjectedObjectFactory`, make it's instance in dagger module as `new InjectedObjectFactory()` and then from activity you call `myInjectedObjectFactory.forActivity(this)` and pass it to presenter.

Comment: Hi man, thanks a lot, I will try the first approach since it seems for me more elegant,
what about the second one, I think it won't work because the presenter can't be created explicitly from the activity but injected. That's why I got into a problem.

Comment: Just looking at the first approach using @Activity scope, why in this case it doesn't create the cross references case.

Comment: At first I thought that you try to have two classes referencing each other, and with slight exceptions in very special cases, that is cyclic dependendency that should be avoided. On the other hand, if you need activity just to create properly InjectedObject (without passing activity reference inside InjectedObject), you can achieve that with scopes.

Comment: Additionally, you should avoid passing reference of activity to presenters (either directly or indirectly via InjectedObject or so). If your activity has any specific logic that is required outside of Activity, extract it to separate class and reference that class from InjectedObject or Presenter.

Comment: Activity should be referenced in presenter *only* for presenter to be able to manage view, in decoupled manner, using some interface. And for that purpose, Activity should not be passed to Injector using constructor but using, let's call them, bind() and unbind() methods on presenter. So that you can bind and unbind view to presenter in onStart() and onStop(), or onResume() and onPause() methods, so that presenter have view bound *only* when view is ready to receive stuff from presenter. That's the only valid reason to have presenter referencing activity, all other stuff are bad smells.

Comment: Just to add, there are some variants of MVP implementations where they do not use bind/unbind methods, but pass view using constructor injector, but I am not comfortable doing it. Still, they pass it only as View interface reference, decoupled. Presenter doesn't know if it is Activity behind that View, or Fragment, or some Fake/Mock object that just verifies method on View being called.

Comment: thanks for clarification, it makes sense I will rethink my current design